# OOP shortening class

Tags: php, oop

This is not so much a question about execution as it is a question about improving code. I am a 2nd year student, we started to touch on OOP recently and I am finally getting the hold of it....sort of.

I realize this is a very basic question, but what better place to learn from some of the best.

**My Question**

I have a class which creates a new match. My problem is that I am sure the code is unnecessary long and can get much improved (just keep in mind it is beginner level).Specifically I would like to know:

- Can I change the below into 1 setter and 1 getter method?
- I would like to use the rand() function for match ID can I do this inside the setter function of setMatchId or should it be done outside of the class?

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this.

```
<?php
class match{
private $matchId;
private $team1;
private $team2;
private $venue; 

function __construct($pMatchId, $pTeam1, $pTeam2, $pVenue){
    $this->matchId = $pMatchId;
    $this->team1 = $pTeam1;
    $this->team2 = $pTeam2;
    $this->venue = $pVenue;
}
    function setMatchId($pMatchId){
        $this->matchId = $pMatchId;

    }

    function getMatchId(){
        return $this->matchId;  

    }
    function setTeam1($pTeam1){
        $this->team1 = $pTeam1; 
    }
    function getTeam1(){
        return $this->team1;    

    }

    function setTeam2($pTeam2){
        $this->team2 = $pTeam2; 
    }
    function getTeam2(){
        return $this->team2;    

    }
    function setVenue($pVenue){
        $this->venue = $pVenue; 

    }
    function getVenue(){
        return $this->venue;    

    }

} // c;lass match

$x = new match("1", "Patriots", "Chargers", "Newlands");
echo $x->getMatchId();
echo'<br />';
echo $x->getTeam1();
echo'<br />';
echo $x->getTeam2();
echo'<br />';
echo $x->getVenue();
?>
```

Comment: I think this would be a good place for you to post the question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Latheesan thank you but it is not a problem with the code, it is just asking for advice to improve it, The wonderful community assisted me with these types of questions many times in the past so I thought it is appropriate to open a new question.  Stupid question - If I post this to codereview, what is Stackoverflow used for then?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for solving specific programming problems.

Comment: To expand on PeeHa, SO mostly used when you have a bug or a problem with your code. Your question is more to do with best practices and writing good code, which is perfect for the CodeReview community.

Comment: The second point is off-topic on CR ("I would like to use the rand() function for match ID can I do this inside the setter function of setMatchId or should it be done outside of the class?), as it's asking for advice about code not yet written. We'd be lacking context in how you'd like to use rand - in those cases you either build it in and then ask whether it's good or leave it out of the question.

Comment: This question is asking for Code Review.

Comment: @Pimgd Thanks mate but I respectfully disagree - I would just like to know Yes it is best practise to do its or NO you would generally do it outside the class

Comment: @AlinPurcaru it is not asking for code review IT IS ASKING FOR HELP/ADVICE, however if you feel I must close the question I will do so.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee I'm just saying that migrating the question as-is is not an option; it will either need editing OR would be closed.

Comment: @Pimgd fair enough, would you mind telling me which part of the question would need editing so that I can do it

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee You are repeatedly saying *Advice, Best Practice, Unnecessary Long, Improved, Should*. All these to me translate to Code Review. As I understand, there's nothing not working in your existing code, it's just that you think it could be better... so again, Code Review.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee If you wanted to post this on Code Review, we'd prefer it if you had a finished implementation. Something you're done with. So for this case, take a look at the advice you already got, use none/some/all of it for implementing the feature, and then post it to Code Review pointing out that "I used rand() for my matchId in order to <reason>" and we'll be able to tell you whether you used the right tool for the job.

Comment: The currently accepted answer is horrible. @holroy answer is much better than others, but I'd strongly advise you to have a look at mine still ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [__set](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) and [__get](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) magic methods of PHP.

```
private $data = array(); // define property array

public function __set($name, $value) // set key and value in data property
{
    echo "Setting '$name' to '$value'\n";
    $this->data[$name] = $value;
}

public function __get($name)  // get propery value
{
  if(isset($this->data[$name])) {
      return $this->data[$name];
  }
}
```

You can write your existing code as below:-

```
class Match{

  private $data = [];

  function __construct($property=[]){
    if(!empty($property)){
      foreach($property as $key=>$value){
        $this->__set($key,$value);
      }
    }
  }

  public function __set($name, $value) // set key and value in data property
  {
      // echo "Setting '$name' to '$value'\n";
      $this->data[$name] = $value;
  }

  public function __get($name)  // get propery value
  {
    if(isset($this->data[$name])) {
        return $this->data[$name];
    }
  }

}
```

**Set properties using construct method**

```
$x = new match(["matchId"=>"1", "team1"=>"Patriots","team2"=>"Chargers","venue"=>"Newlands"]);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($x);
```

**Set properties without construct method**

```
$x = new match;
$x->matchId = '1'; // 1
$x->team1 = 'team1';  // Patriots
$x->team2 = 'Chargers';  // Chargers
$x->venue = 'Newlands';  // Newlands
echo '<pre>'; print_r($x);
```

**output**:-

```
Match Object
(
    [data:Match:private] => Array
        (
            [matchId] => 1
            [team1] => Patriots
            [team2] => Chargers
            [venue] => Newlands
        )

)
```

Now you can access and set propery by below way:-

```
// Get all properties values
echo $x->matchId; // 1
echo $x->team1;  // Patriots
echo $x->team2;  // Chargers
echo $x->venue;  // Newlands

// Overwrite existing values 
$x->team1 = 'new team1';
// Get updated value
echo $x->team1;  // new team1
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee curious which version of PHP you're using.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I am using PHP 5.5.32 :)

Comment: @RaviHirani I pinged the OP, not you ;-) notice *"@TimothyCoetzee curious which version of PHP you're using."*

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Ohh sorry for misunderstanding!!

Comment: @RaviHirani thanks for that great detailed answer, im using php 5.5

Comment: There's one limit with this solution when having only `private` fields (like OP question). In fact, if a field is private `__get` and `__set` are not used. Hence when you have private field you should again declare specific getters and setters..

Comment: @FredMaggiowski: In my answer,  I have declared private $data = [];

Comment: Yeah, had to make sure in regards to `[]`.

Comment: @RaviHirani my fault, i haven't seen it :)

Comment: @FredMaggiowski: Np. Sometimes it also happens with me :-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yes. Agree with you :)

Comment: @RaviHirani Great detailed Answer! :)

Comment: @ShashankShah: Thanks brother :-)

Answer (score 2):

How often are teams or venues going to change for a match? I think you should get rid of the setters since you're already providing all the necessary data through your constructor.

You can indeed change your code to work with a single getter and setter methods, but I'd strongly discourage that. IDE's won't be able to assist you with code completion if you implement such methods but, most importantly, you should never blindly implement getters and setters in your entities if they have no reason to exist.

Let the design guide you on that. Start by passing everything your objects need through their constructors and only add getters/setters when you need them, not the other way around.

In terms of the randomness of the ID, you could use UUIDs for them. You could use [this library](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) to create them. I'd pass them through its constructor as well.

Comment: @hansumedic Thank you for your input, much appreciated. Teams and Venues change after each match. Are you saying except for the setters the code is implemented "okay"

Comment: If teams and venues are changing after each match, you're telling me that they are a **new** match. More reason for those setters to cease to exist. You don't need to re-use the same Match instance, simply create a new one. In terms of the correctness of the implementation, there's not much logic going on in that class, neither we are aware of its context, so it's difficult to say if it's 'correct'.

Comment: Thanks mate I removed them, and it makes much more sense

Answer (score 1):

The first question:

> Can I change the below into 1 setter and 1 getter method?

[EDIT] Reply to first comment:

You can, but you shouldn't.. To me it's better keep all setters and getters parted. You might want to get only a specific field when using your `match` object instance in your code. So if you need to get team1 or team2 it's better to have two different getter methods.

The second question:

> I would like to use the rand() function for match ID can I do this inside the setter function of setMatchId or should it be done outside of the class?

Well, in my opinion, the best way of handle it is to disallow any access to the `$matchId` field making it private and removing any setter method.
Then, you should place the rand generation inside the constructor or, if you want to keep it parted in a specific function you could make a public getter like this:

```
public getMatchId(){
    if ($this->matchId != null)
        return $this->matchId

     // Generate it with rand()
     $this->matchId = rand()
     return $this->matchId;
}
```

In the constructor then simply call the `getMatchId()` method.

By the way, this solution doesn't help you with getting a unique match identifier, to achieve that you should generate it not purely randomly but using something that is dependant of the informations of the Match (for instance you could use a combination of `team1`, `team2` and `venue`) and/or keep track of used matchid (a static field or a database could be helpful)

[EDIT] Reply to second comment:

I'm using the `if statement` in the getter because this getter is thought to generate the `$matchId` when it's called for the first time, while it'll always return the previously generated `$matchId` for the other calls.

You question made me think of another possible implementation. If you want to avoid the `if` then you should generate the $matchId in the constructor.

This way should be fine:

```
public __construct($team1, $team2, $venue){
     $this->matchId = rand();
     $this->team1 = $team1;
     $this->team2 = $team2;
     $this->venue = $venue
}

public getMatchId(){
     return $this->matchId;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fred, as for point 1 (the first question) I am simply implying can all the above be achieved in 2 methods rather than having a separate method for each property...if that makes sense, your other info was very helpful thank you

Comment: One Question Please why are you using an `if statment` inside the getter. Can you not just do this `public getMatchId(){  // Generate it with rand()
     $this->matchId = rand()
     return $this->matchId;`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple answers covering how to do setters and getters in various degrees of complexity and magic. In this post I would rather focus on the design quality of your class `Match`. This is based on the design idea related to *what do you want to use your class for?*

Some typical statements answering this question:

- *Keep record of a given match* – In other words it needs to hold information related to *one* match, i.e. `venue`, `homeTeam`, `awayTeam`, `result`?, and possibly a `matchId` related to storing the result somewhere
- *Set the result of a match* – You'll create the match, and then a little later you'll set the actual result of the match.
- *Store a match* – If you don't store it anywhere it is kind of futile to keep track of the match, so most likely you would need some interface either to a database, or some mean to get all information related to a match ready for storing into a file or similar
- *Ability to retrieve the details of a match* – If not getting all information at the same time, you could opt for a getter for the specific values you'll want.

For me I don't see the need for changing the team or venue, as that would mean a new match in my world. And I would definitively *not* implement a generic setter which would allow for setting whatever to whatever. A generic setter is a security risk in my world.

### Alternate implementation

Adhering to the statements given I would write something similar to this:

```
<?php

class Match {
    private $matchId;
    private $homeTeam;
    private $awayTeam;
    private $venue; 
    private $result;

    function __construct($venue, $homeTeam, $awayTeam, $matchId = NULL) {
        $this->venue = $venue;
        $this->homeTeam = $homeTeam;
        $this->awayTeam = $awayTeam;

        if (is_null($matchId)) {
            $this->matchId = uniqid();
        } else {
            $this->matchId = $matchId;
        }
        // In PHP7:   $this->matchId = $matchId ?: uniqid();

        $this->result = "";
    }

    function setResult($result){
        $this->result = $result;
    }

    function getAll(){
        return array($this->venue, $this->homeTeam, $this->awayTeam,
                     $this->matchId, $this->result);  
    }

    function __get($name) {
        if (property_exist($this, $name)) {
            return $this->$name;
        }
    }

    function __set($name, $value) {
        if (property_exist($this, $name)) {
            $this->$name = $value;
    }
} 

?>
```

Some comments related to this code:

- `homeTeam` and `awayTeam` – Having variables name `team1` or `team2` is a code smell, to me. I would either create an array for those, or find better names. In this case I opted for better names to make a clear distinction between the two variables.
- `__construct()` – When creating a match the default value for `matchId` indicates that it will be set to a [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). I consider this a better practice rather then using a random value. And it still allows for setting a specific match id if you want to provide this.

  Based on the assumption that you don't know the result when the match is created, the result is set to an empty string for starters.
- `setResult()` – As this is the only part of a match I foresee changing I provided a setter for this value.
- `getAll()` – This returns an array of all the values, ready for storing somewhere. If you like this could easily be changed into a comma separated string or whatever format you would like for post-processing. It could even be a dictionary, but I just used a simple array to keep it simple.
- `__get()` and `__set()` – Contrary to some of the other answers this getter (and setter) is a little safer to use as it verifies that the actual property is defined in this class using [property_exist()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php).

  I'm not sure if I would actually have the generic setter, but if you'd like one, this is a better option as it doesn't allow for creation of new properties to your class at runtime.

## Usage of class

Here is some simple usage of the class (if my untested code actually works, that is):

```
<!php
    $m = new Match("Newlands", "Patriots", "Chargers");
    // Time passes
    $m->setResult("102-32");

    echo 'In the game ' . $m->homeTeam . ' vs ' . $m->awayTeam
    echo ' at ' . $m ->venue ' the result was ' . $m->result . ' <br />'

    // Append the match to a file
    $fp = fopen('allmatches.csv', 'a');
    fputcsv($fp, $m->getAll());
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

This uses [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to format the array into a line in the csv format. Having a method or some way to create a match from an array is left as an exercise. You possibly have a static method taking a file name as a parameter, and return an array of matches.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good or bad model when you aren't trying to solve a well-defined problem just like there's no good answer to a bad question.

Before even worrying about things such as getters and setters you need to determine the purpose of the model and what problem it is trying to solve.

I understand that this is probably just a modeling exercise, but if you want it to have any value, start by defining your problem domain and then work out the solution.

For instance, if you are modeling an application service that allows to query a list of matches, then perhaps `Match` is a simple immutable data structure that acts as a [Data Transfer Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html).

If you were modeling a [ViewModel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) that is meant to be 2-way bound to a CRUD screen allowing to update the details of a `Match` then perhaps you'd have a data container with public getters and setters like you had.

If you were crafting a tournament system [domain model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) and had a use case such as: "Tournament administrators will enter the scoring of a match after it's completion. The outcome will be automatically resolved by the system. The possible results are that the home/away team wins or a draw."

Then perhaps `Match` would carry a behavior such as (pseudo-code):

```
scoring = new Scoring(homeTeamScore: 2, awayTeamScore: 3);
match.complete(scoring);
match.outcome(); //-> MatchOutcome.AwayTeamWon
```

As you can see, the model should be a solution to a well-defined problem. It should model the reality of that problem (not the real world), no more, no less.

> I would like to use the rand() function for match ID can I do this
>   inside the setter function of setMatchId or should it be done outside
>   of the class?

The generation of an entity's identity is usually not the responsibility of the identity itself in respect to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). The algorithm that generates the identity may change independently of the `Match` concept itself.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, there's nothing bad in having several get/set methods, unless you're coding on a 64kb RAM machine (Where you probably would use C, Lua, or such instead of PHP). If they're all doing (almost) the same thing and you think they're messing code up, put them on the very end of your class, so they don't block your vision ;-).

For the practical altering of your code:

If you have several members which differ only by data but actually represent the same kind, like team1, team2 puting them into an array and use a get/setByIndex is legit.

(Take care: I didn't use PHP for hundreds of years or so, there might me syntactical mistakes)

Example:

```
function setTeamByIndex($pIndex, $pTeam){
    $this->teams[$pIndex] = $pTeam; 
}
function getTeamByIndex($pIndex){
    return $this->team[$pIndex];    

}
```

Alternatively, in other language it's common to return multiple values. This is not possible in PHP, but there's a workaround:

setTeamsFromArray
 -- receives an Array with teams and applies the given teams by their key.
getAllTeamsArray
 -- returns an Array, containing all teams.

```
function setTeamsFromArray($pTeams){
    foreach ($pTeams as $key=>$team) {
       $this->teams[$key] = $team
    }
}
function getAllTeamsArray(){
     return array( $this->team1, $this->team2 )
} 

echo(getAllTeamsArray()[0]) -> echos team1
echo(getAllTeamsArray()[1]) -> echos team2
```

In my opinion, this is all one reasonable could do in your case.
Shrinking stuff down is not always reasonable and 10 4liners are, most of the time, better than 1 40liner.

Answer (score -3):

for geter and seter you can use __call() magic method for example realize the geters and setters

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    // TODO: Implement __call() method.
    $method = substr($name,0,3);
    $key = strtolower(substr($name,3,strlen($name)));
    if($method == 'set') {
        $this->_data[$key] = $argument[0]
        return $this;
    } elseif($method=='get') {
        if(isset($this->_data[$key])) {
            return $this->_data[$key];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

this is simple realization getter and setter automaticaly generate.

Comment: I didn't downvote, however I kind of understand why one would. TO is beginner with almost no real life coding experience and just slightly above 12months of university coding experience. Your answer contains a, for beginner, hard to read sniped and lacks of explanation for beginner. Also, while it's possible and in some languages legit, universal get/set methods aren't ideal. They're slow, hard to understand and to maintain. The only pro side of such a method is how short it is. But what's the value of short code, if it's neither readable nor fast?

Comment: sorry but I can't full description my answer because I bad know English.

Comment: I used the term "beginner" 3 times in 2 following sentences. So one easily could spot that my english isn't that good as well. Doesn't matter, one can understand and I'm only getting better by using the language I've not mastered ;-)